# jQuery Validation - error placement

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to use 'errorPlacement' from jQuery Validation **[DOCS](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions):**

```
$("#myform").validate({
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
     error.appendTo( element.parent("td").next("td") );
   },
   debug:true
 })
```

I want to place error **before** not valid input, but this does not work:

```
$("#myform").validate({
      errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
         error.appendTo( element.parent("form").prev("input") );
       },
       debug:true
     })
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/MmhsW/)**

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: what does the markup look like and where in that markup do you want to put the error?

Comment: @kinakuta - live demo has been added to the question

Comment: so you want the error message to appear above the respective text box?

Comment: @kinakuta Yes, before (on top) given input.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Since you want to insert the error message before the invalid element, use [insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/):

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.insertBefore(element);
}
```

Comment: Hamidi Thanks! That is working! Nearly.. as you can see in my example - there are actually two input for password(one for onfocus effect and one real one), can we speficy that for #username insertbefore(); and for #realpassword insertBefore('#password') ??

Comment: This is working correctly only for #password:

 `errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
     if( $('label[for="realpassword"]') ){ error.insertBefore('#password'); }
     else if (('label[for="username"]')){ error.insertBefore('#username'); }
        
    },` Why??

Comment: @Pete, it should work but the error message still appears after the `<input>` element in my browser. The floating parent `<span>` seems to be the problem...

Comment: Hamidi -  but #username is outside of it.. :| Same story without `<span>`

Comment: if we change the order - both appear on top of #user `errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
     if ( $('label[for="username"]') ){ error.insertBefore('#username'); }
     else if( $('label[for="realpassword"]') ){ error.insertBefore('#password'); }
    },`

Comment: @Pete, nearly all your elements are styled with `float: left;` and `display: inline-block;`. That's messing with the layout. Is there a reason why you do that?

Comment: Sorted! Float are cos this submit btn.

Answer (score 18):

Just put the part Where you want the error

```
<label for="[your checkbox id]" generated="true" class="error"></label>
```

Ex:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="1" > Checkbox content</label>
<label for="checkbox" generated="true" class="error"></label>
```

Answer (score 6):

I recommend to use a html template to specify the position and styling like so:

```
<input name="patient_gender" required>
<label for="patient_gender" class="validation_error_message help-block"></label>
```

and overwrite function for error placement

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        var name = element.attr('name');
        var errorSelector = '.validation_error_message[for="' + name + '"]';
        var $element = $(errorSelector);
        if ($element.length) { 
            $(errorSelector).html(error.html());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is...

```
  errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    element.before(error);
  }
```