# JQuery validation error placement repeating itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

**1.** Whenever an error pops up it usually repeats itself to another line as you can see from the example image.

[image: Error Message Repeats]

**2.** And for some reason the custom messages are not appearing either, when I click on submit it says **This field is required** are the custom messages not working anymore?

Any help on how to solve this will be amazing, I've been trying to figure this out for 3 days, but can't find any help online. I'm a noob in JQuery Validation so please be detailed in your response. Thank you!

**JQuery Code:** I'm using Bootstrap 4 and jQuery 3.2.1, and jQuery Validate

```
$('.contactForm').validate ({

  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
     error.appendTo('.error');
   },

        rules: {
            fullname: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                maxlength: 20
            },

          email: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8,
                maxlength: 40
            },
            subject: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4,
                maxlength: 33
            },

            comment: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 10,
            },

        messages: {
            fullname: {
                required: "Please enter your first and last name",
                minlength: "Names can't be shorter than 5 characters",
                maxlength: "Names can't be longer than 20 characters"
            },
             email: {
                required: "Please enter your full email address",
                minlength: "Emails can't be shorter than 8 characters",
                maxlength: "Emails can't be longer than 40 characters"
            },
                  subject: {
                required: "Please enter a subject for your message",
                minlength: "Subjects can't be shorter than 4 characters",
                maxlength: "Subjects can't be longer than 33 characters"
            },
                  comment: {
                required: "Please type your message here",
                minlength: "Message must be at least 10 characters long"
            },

                highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
    }    
        },

  submitHandler: function() {  
            $('#noenter').show();   

        }
}
    });
```

**HTML:**

```
<form class="contactForm" method="post" action="">
 <div class="form-row mx-3">
   <div class="forms col-md-12 mb-3">
   <label class="bigsentence text-white font-weight-bold" for="fullname"><i class="text-danger pr-1 fas fa-id-card"></i>Name:<span class="ml-2 text-danger error"></span> </label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullname" id="fullname" placeholder="Your Full Name"> 
   </div>

   <div class="forms col-md-12 mb-3">
   <label class="bigsentence text-white font-weight-bold" for="email"><i class="text-danger pr-1 fas fa-at"></i>Email:<span class="ml-2 text-danger error"></span></label>
   <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Your Email Address"> 
   </div>

   <div class="forms col-md-12 mb-3">
   <label class="bigsentence text-white font-weight-bold" for="subject"><i class="text-danger pr-1 fas fa-info-circle"></i>Subject: <span class="ml-2 text-danger error"></span></label>
   <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="Reason for contact"> 
   </div>

   <div  class="col-md-12 mb-3">
   <div class="forms form-group">
   <label class="bigsentence font-weight-bold text-white" for="comment"><i class="text-danger pr-1 fas fa-pen-square"></i>Message: <span class="ml-2 text-danger error"></span></label>
   <textarea type="text" name="comment" class="form-control" rows="4" id="comment" placeholder="Type your message here"></textarea>
   </div>
   </div>
 <div  class="col-md-12 mb-3">

 <button style="max-width:280px;" name="send" type="submit" class="rsvpbtn btn btn-block btn-danger sendmessage">SEND MESSAGE</button>

</div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Please be careful with those tags and tag-spam.  The jQuery Validate Engine is not the same plugin.  Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `errorPlacement` function uses just a class, one found in all error elements. Therefore each error gets appended to all four error elements.

Use this instead:

```
error.appendTo(element.parent().find("span"));
```

Comment: For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545964/jquery-validation-error-placement

Comment: Awesome, I get it I was appending to the error. Thanks for pointing that out. Do you also happen to know why it gives me: This field is required instead of the custom message?

Comment: @ChosenJuan Yes, if you check your indentation you'll find that `messages` is a child of `rules`, but supposed to be a sibling.

Comment: @ChosenJuan, your parenthesis are all jacked up.  You've put the `messages` object *inside* the `rules` object so it's being ignored.  You've also put the `highlight` object inside of the `messages` object so its also being ignored.

Comment: Thank you both, it always comes down to the syntax. I'll be more careful next time. Cheers!